# Qdebug, QDialog, QMainwindow in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, qt

i'm new to c++ and QT programming and this question could be super stupid for you..

I'm trying to run a third parties program with visual studio 2019..it uses opencv, boost and QT libraries... through windows power shell and vcpkg I've successfully installed all the opencv and boost libraires but i'm not able to fix the problem with the QTones.. when I compile the code I have the following errors

E1696 impossible to open 'Qdebug' from file origin.
E1696 impossible to open 'QDialog' from file origin.
E1696 impossible to open 'QMainWindows' from file origin.

I've installed the Qt Vs tools extention but it didn't solve the problem..

should I need to istall QT or there is a way to install only the packages that I need through vpck as I did with the other libraries? was it correct to download the Qt extention?

an other thing.. this code has also and application File... if I try to launch it I have the following errors: Qt5Core,QTGui,QT5Widgets.dll not found

please help me.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download qt,qt is a is a development tool，after you installed qt , you can configure in vs, add the qmake and others qt tools.